# How can I update an component based on a variable change in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I need to render the `Todo` component based on the "currentTodo", like, if my `currentTodo` is 2, it should render the "Todo" based on the object that has the `todoId` 2. By the way, I'm changing the `currentTodo` inside the `Navbar` component.

```
function App() {

  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([
    {
      todoId: 0,
      todoName: "Personal",
      todoTasks: []
    },
    {
      todoId: 1,
      todoName: "Work",
      todoTasks: []
    },
    {
      todoId: 2,
      todoName: "College",
      todoTasks: []
    }
  ])

  const[currentTodo, setCurrentTodo] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar 
        todo = {todoList}
        currentTodo = {currentTodo}
        setCurrentTodo = {setCurrentTodo}
      />
      {
        todoList.map((todo) => {
          if(todo.todoId === currentTodo){
            return(
              <Todo 
                currentTodo = {currentTodo}
                todoList = {todoList}
                setTodoList = {setTodoList}
                id = {todoList.todoId}
              />
            )
          }})
      }
      {console.log(currentTodo)}
      {console.log(todoList[currentTodo])}
      
    </>
  )
}
```

But when I try to change the `currentTodo` value dynamically, the `Todo` component simply disappears.
 How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Robo's answer it is better to use `.find` rather than `.map` and check for each interaction. however, your solution should work and I think you are facing another issue.

when you update `currentTodo` dynamically from your navbar, and this new value of `currentTodo` does not match any of the ids, then there is no `Todo` component displayed, the problem should be how you are updating it.
 If you set the value to a string

```js
setCurrentTodo("2"); //example
```

then `===` will not match unless you change it to `==` or just set the new value to a number:

```js
setCurrentTodo(2); //example
setCurrentTodo(Number(event.target.value));
```

Comment: That is exactly what was happening, i was assinging a string to it and didn't notice, thanks so much!

Comment: @Anonymous_- you are welcome, happy to help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()` method on your todo array to find the matching todo.

```
function App() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([
    // ...
  ]);

  // I added the "Id" suffix to make it clear what it is
  const[currentTodoId, setCurrentTodoId] = useState(0);

  const todo = todoList.find(
    ({ todoId }) => todoId === currentTodoId
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar 
        todo = {todoList}
        currentTodo = {currentTodoId}
        setCurrentTodo = {setCurrentTodo}
      />
      {todo !== undefined && (
        <Todo
          currentTodo = {currentTodoId}
          todoList = {todoList}
          setTodoList = {setTodoList}
          id = {currentTodoId}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

By the way, the props of your `<Todo />` component look a bit off. You probably want to make it get an event handler instead of giving it a setter.

You can also consider using `useMemo()` for finding the matching todo with `.find()`, but it's unnecessary unless you're having thousands of todos and/or you're re-rendering a lot.

Comment: Thanks man, i didn't really know about this method, it's much better now!